# React: How to prevent unnecessary re-rendering of a child component in React when modifying a parent's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a scenario in React where a parent component maintains a state value and passes it to a child component. The child component uses this state in its useEffect and sometimes modifies the parent's state. When the state changes, it is passed back to the child component, causing the child component to re-render. How can I prevent the child component from re-rendering due to its own modification of the parent's state?

I was expecting that these optimizations would prevent unnecessary re-rendering of the child component when it modifies the parent's state

Comment: The child component has to accept changes to the parent component's State, but also wants to avoid rendering the child component as a result of its own changes to the State.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the child component with `React.memo()` to memoize it. This means that the component will only re-render if its props change.

```
const Child = React.memo(({ value }) => {
  return(
    <div>{value}</div>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But the child still re-renders when the value changes, I was trying to avoid, the rendering of the Child caused when the Child makes a change to the Value (but if the value is not changed by the Child, the Child still needs to render)

Comment: if the props are different?, the child component will re-render even with React.memo().

also cehck if if the parent component is also re-rendering when the child component changes the value